# create-react-app doesn't support `yield`?

Tags: ecmascript-6, yield, create-react-app

I created a project using `create-react-app` but when I write some code with the keyword `yield`, the page shows building error claiming 'Unexpected token' at `yield`.

[image]

Is there a way to enable `yield` in `create-react-app` projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to mark the function as a Generator by using the `*` symbol?

```
function fn() {
    yield "some value";
}
```

This code results in a syntax error, since the yield keyword is not allowed in normal functions.

```
function *generatorFn() {
    yield "some value";
}
```

This code does not result in a syntax error, since the function is a generator.

For an example see [this snippet](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=function%20helloworld()%20%7B%0A%20%20yield%20%22var%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20*helloworld()%20%7B%0A%20%20yield%20%22var%22%3B%0A%7D&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true)